# Выбор последних записей из таблицы без указания индекса

Tags: sql

В SQL есть запрос выбирающий первые записи

```
SELECT TOP 1000 ...
```

Прекрасная сторона запроса в том, что не надо указывать индекс. Можно выбрать последние записи, но уже указываем по какому параметру

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY table_id DESC
```

Есть ли команда выбора последних записей из таблицы, без указания индекса?

```
SELECT BOTTOM 1000 ( такая команда не работает )
```

P.S. Ответ нет такого — тоже ответ.

Comment: вы можете узнать кол-во записей через count и поставить смещение в выборке (офсет)  на 1000 меньше, чем count.

Comment: Без order by понятия первых и последних записей в принципе не существует. СУБД _не гарантирует_ порядка выбора записей и "последние" записи не обязательно в самом конце выборки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как верно заметили выше в комментарии к вопросу - первых и последних записей не существует, и СУБД не гарантирует порядок возвращаемых строк. TOP без указания ORDER BY при этом использует внутренний механизм хранения данных - по имени таблицы мы получаем доступ к первой странице данных, в первой странице есть ссылка на вторую, во второй - на третью, и так далее.

Поэтому, движок, получив инструкцию вернуть первые строки без указания порядка, идет на первую страницу, вычитывает нужное количество строк, если их не хватает, он идет на вторую страницу, вычитывает следующую порцию, и делает так, пока не наберет нужного количества, или пока таблица не закончится.

И, поскольку сервер не гарантирует никакого конкретного порядка возвращаемых данных, он считает, что, раз вы не указали ORDER BY, вам без разницы, какой именно набор данных вам получить (иначе вы бы указали, как отсортировать данные, прежде чем вернуть ограниченный набор), и можно использовать самый дешевый способ доступа к данным - нет никакого смысла в том, чтобы сначала добраться по ссылкам до последней страницы, и потом начинать вычитывать данные с конца.